# Decimal places get rounded in line by line output with cat()

Tags: r

When I print a vector in R line by line with `cat()`, results are rounded differently than in the usual output:

```
> dbinom(0:10, 10, 0.95)
 [1] 9.765625e-14 1.855469e-11 1.586426e-09 8.037891e-08 2.672599e-06
 [6] 6.093525e-05 9.648081e-04 1.047506e-02 7.463480e-02 3.151247e-01
[11] 5.987369e-01
> options(scipen=999)
> dbinom(0:10, 10, 0.95)
 [1] 0.00000000000009765625 0.00000000001855468750 0.00000000158642578125
 [4] 0.00000008037890625000 0.00000267259863281252 0.00006093524882812524
 [7] 0.00096480810644531680 0.01047505944140628489 0.07463479852001964066
[10] 0.31512470486230492739 0.59873693923837867370
> cat(dbinom(0:10, 10, 0.95), sep = "\n")
0.00000000000009765625
0.00000000001855469
0.000000001586426
0.00000008037891
0.000002672599
0.00006093525
0.0009648081
0.01047506
0.0746348
0.3151247
0.5987369
```

How can I preserve the decimal places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using `sprintf`:

```
> cat(sprintf("%.20f", dbinom(0:10, 10, 0.95)),sep="\n")
0.00000000000009765625
0.00000000001855468750
0.00000000158642578125
0.00000008037890625000
0.00000267259863281251
0.00006093524882812514
0.00096480810644531680
0.01047505944140628489
0.07463479852001966841
0.31512470486230481637
0.59873693923837867370
```

I should also mention that any precision beyond 15 digits is probably spurious at best using floating point calculations. Notice that `0.31512470486230492739` in your data and `0.31512470486230481637` in mine don't match beyond 15 digits.

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect! A return question, though: Why doesn't normal output round to the R-system-wide default precision of 6 decimal points?

Comment: @what - AFAIK it's actually 7 digits by default, regardless of decimal places. Set `options(scipen=0)` and try `123.11111111` and note it rounds for printing to `123.1111`. Likewise `9.765625e-14` has 7 significant digits and R just adds 13 zeroes in front (moves the decimal place 14 spaces to the left) when `cat`ing. I admittedly don't fully understand the ins-and-outs of the R internals when it comes to this.